# Error con malloc() sin llamarlo directamente

Tags: c++

quería saber si alguien sabe porque me aparece el siguiente error `malloc(): corrupted top size`.

No estoy usando directamente la llamada malloc() (ahora muestro el código), pero se usa en otra parte del código el cual no ha sido modificado. El error viene a partir de estas líneas: `recorrido[pos].nodos[ocu].idDelNodo = cuda_nodes[id_s][i].id;` en el que `pos` es un entero y `ocu` otro.

Muestro como está definido `recorrido`:

En el .h:

```
datos* recorrido;

typedef struct
{
  int v;
  contenido nodos[MAX];
}datos;

typedef struct
{
  int idDelNodo;
  int otroDato;
}contenido;
```

En el .cpp:

```
En el constructor recorrido = NULL;
recorrido = new datos [max];
```

Comment: `qué es MAX`? ¿cuánto vale `max`? Y piensa que es preferible poner el constructor con la inicialización de `recorrido` a decir cómo lo has inicializado

Comment: deberías ponernos un caso de prueba que falle. Con lo que has puesto en tu pregunta es imposible darte una respuesta